# How do I find elements from Google forms? (elements by NAME, ID, XPATH etc.)

Tags: python-3.x, forms, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook, pycharm

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdl0XfeoCuPwO4bN7tEzpkKC7vUHa2xfQiw3Tyz8X1RbEyFLA/viewform"
driver.get(url)

def fill_form(firstname, lastname, gender, age):
    inputs = driver.find_element(By.ID, "mG61Hd")
    
    time.sleep(2)
    inputs_array = [
        firstname, lastname, age
    ]
    for i in range(inputs):
        inputs[i].clear()
        inputs[i].send_keys(inputs_array[i])
fill_form("syed", "haider", "male", "22")
```

[image]

I need to automate google forms using Selenium, and I am stuck here.

I don't know how do I find elements by attributes NAME, ID and XPATH (obviously I need one of them) but I don't know which one is it. I have tried replacing several elements and none of them working.

Here is the link for the mock forms,
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdl0XfeoCuPwO4bN7tEzpkKC7vUHa2xfQiw3Tyz8X1RbEyFLA/viewform

I'll be working on a project but as a test how it works I created a mock form and I am stuck in picking elements from the form.

Comment: Share your code trials and also share the HTML in text form(not image).

Comment: Maybe `/html/body/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]` XPATH for getting the the different form fields

Comment: here is the html in text form.
<input type="text" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="i1" aria-describedby="i2 i3" required="" dir="auto" data-initial-dir="auto" data-initial-value="">

Comment: Can you put your code in a code block within the post? Thanks!

Comment: @Shawn just checking it.

Answer (score 1):

```
//span[text()='First Name']//following::input[1]
```

Above XPath expression will locate the *text box* to enter **First Name**

[image]

Same way you can construct XPath expressions for other fields such as **Last Name** and **Age**.

**Explanation of XPath expression:**

- `//span` - Finds all the `<span>` nodes
- `[text()='First Name']` - Finds all the text containing **First Name**
- `//following::input[1]` - Finds the following first `<input>` node

So in summary, finds the first `input` node which is immediately after the `span` node containing text **First Name**

Comment: from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\Qura tul Ain\Documents\FORM\chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdl0XfeoCuPwO4bN7tEzpkKC7vUHa2xfQiw3Tyz8X1RbEyFLA/viewform"
driver.get(url)
first_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='First Name']//following::input[1]")
first_name[0].send_keys("Syed")
I used it but it throws the following error.

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_4460/1922273219.py in <module>
      7 driver.get(url)
      8 first_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='First Name']//following::input[1]")
----> 9 first_name[0].send_keys("Syed")

TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable

Comment: if you code is like this `first_name[0].send_keys("Syed")`. Change it to `first_name.send_keys("Syed")`

Comment: actually my demo code working with CSS_SELECTOR but I don't know what is it and how do I write it manually? can you help?

Comment: and how do i write xpath for radiobuttons?

Comment: Try this for radio buttons - `//span[text()='Male']//preceding::div[1]`

Comment: can I code it so that it randomly select either male or female option? how? should i use random module?

Comment: @XcorpionXyed - This is a different question altogether. If your original issue has been resolved, please accept this answer or upvote if it was helpful. You can ask a new question regarding selecting the radio buttons randomly, so that the wider community audience will be able to help you.